# setting gvim as editor for crontab

Tags: linux, gvim, crontab

I've see many post saying that by setting the following evnironment variable

```
EDITOR=vim
```

or

```
VISUAL=vim
```

will allow to use `vim` as code editor for crontab.

I would likt to try to use `gvim` instead of vim,  so I stick it in that environment variable, but every time I call `crontab -e` a blank page appears.

Is it something missing there? Is it doable?

I am using `CENTOS 6.5`.

Comment: `VISUAL=gvim crontab -e` works fine for me; you DO have it installed, don't you? Also, you need to make sure `$DISPLAY` is set (`sudo VISUAL=gvim crontab -e` might not work).

Comment: Works for me too.  Try from the command line first a.k.a. Try manually.  cd /var/spool/cron and then "gvim root" and see if it works.  If so, you should be able to use the above variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the -f parameter to let gvim start in foreground mode:

```
EDITOR='gvim -f' crontab -e
```

Comment: Awesame! It works like a charm!

Comment: If that doesn't work try `VISUAL='gvim -f' ...`